# gpg: clear-sign failed: Permission denied

Tags: gnupg

I'm trying to build a debian package from a very simple "hithere"/helloworld c code. I'm getting this error

```
$ DEBNAME="Maintainer" DEBEMAIL=user@buildserver.org debmake -a hithere-0.8.1.tar.gz -T -i debuild

...
W: hithere: copyright-without-copyright-notice
W: hithere: readme-debian-contains-invalid-email-address bogus@localhost
W: hithere: extended-description-line-too-long
E: hithere: maintainer-name-missing <bogus@localhost>
E: hithere: maintainer-address-malformed <bogus@localhost>
E: hithere: maintainer-address-is-on-localhost <bogus@localhost>
W: hithere: unknown-section local
Finished running lintian.
Now signing changes and any dsc files...
 signfile dsc hithere_0.8.1-1.dsc <bogus@localhost>
gpg --local-user "<bogus@localhost>" --clearsign  --list-options no-show-policy-urls --armor --textmode --output "/tmp/debsign.XYoWdyn7/hithere_0.8.1-1.dsc.asc" "/tmp/debsign.XYoWdyn7/hithere_0.8.1-1.dsc"
gpg: signing failed: Permission denied
gpg: /tmp/debsign.XYoWdyn7/hithere_0.8.1-1.dsc: clear-sign failed: Permission denied
debsign: gpg error occurred!  Aborting....
debuild: fatal error at line 1045:
running debsign failed
E: failed to build Debian package(s).
```

Isolating the command I get the same:

```
$gpg --local-user "<bogus@localhost>" --clearsign  --list-options no-show-policy-urls --armor --textmode test 
gpg: signing failed: Permission denied
gpg: test: clear-sign failed: Permission denied
```

No luck with strace:

```
$strace gpg --local-user "<bogus@localhost>" --clearsign  --list-options no-show-policy-urls --armor --textmode test 
strace: ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, ...): Operation not permitted
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

this is my gnupg

```
$ls ~/.gnupg/
openpgp-revocs.d  private-keys-v1.d  pubring.kbx  pubring.kbx~  S.gpg-agent  S.gpg-agent.browser  S.gpg-agent.extra  S.gpg-agent.ssh  trustdb.gpg
```

Thanks for any help